# Помогите составить запрос

Tags: sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT   t.Q_ID, t1.Q_ID
FROM     ut t JOIN ut t1 ON t1.V_ID = t.V_ID AND t.Q_ID < t1.Q_ID
GROUP BY t.Q_ID, t1.Q_ID
```

Но нужно получить что-то вроде:

```
SELECT   t.Q_ID, t1.Q_ID
FROM     ut t JOIN ut t1 ON sum(t1.V_ID) = sum(t.V_ID) AND t.Q_ID < t1.Q_ID
GROUP BY t.Q_ID, t1.Q_ID
```

Нужно тоже самое только по суммам. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: вместо таблиц используйте подзапросы, которые вернут суммы в нужном разрезе

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Не имея точного представления, что вам нужно получить, я все же бы предложил условие по суммам перенести в HAVING:

```
SELECT   t.Q_ID, t1.Q_ID
FROM     #t as t JOIN #t t1 ON t.Q_ID < t1.Q_ID
GROUP BY t.Q_ID, t1.Q_ID
having  sum(t1.V_ID) = sum(t.V_ID)
```

Более точный ответ можно дать, если вы опишете словами, что хотите получить, и назовете СУБД и версию, для которой пишете скрипт - в некоторых СУБД реализованы более удобные функции для таких операций.